# error while implementing nghandsontable in angularjs soution

Tags: angularjs

I am trying get a grid in my solution through nghandsontable. I have downloaded zip file in github and included the services and directive folders and nghandsontable.js in solution.

And used the script

```
    <script src="../libs/angular/ngHandsontable.js"></script>
```

in html.
And Css file which is mentioned in github website is not available in downloaded zip folder.

while im using "hot-table" element. Im getting error as unknown element.

```
    <hot-table datarows="db.items"></hot-table>
```

Im a newbie and an using third party solution for the first time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which css file is missing? add your code snippet here.

Comment: make sure you have this in your directory https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable/blob/develop/dist/ngHandsontable.min.js

Comment: I have added links to download the respective ones.. let me know

Comment: I used those links but getting while compiling that Nodejs has be updated to Node0.10.20. Is there any other gridviews i can use ?(drag & drop of rows sorting feature is needed).

Comment: goto those links and save locally and use that reference..

Comment: tried that too. i still getting the same error "unknown element" for "hot-table".

Comment: in console you still see errors? if yes, show your project folder structure..

Answer (score 0):

Resources:

handsontable.full.c‌​ss: 
http://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css

handsontable.full.js‌: 
http://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js

ngHandsontable.js
http://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/dist/ngHandsontable.js

I hope you have angularjs already in place.